# Unix: C-shell:Rename the duplicate files

Tags: unix, rename, csh

I have lot of folder in the similar format; no-no-alpha*-no; ex :11DATA20, 12DATA21, 13DATA22.

The task is to rename the directory by removing two numbers at the front; ex: 11DATA20 to DATA20.

So far, this is my code:

```
foreach file(`find . -type d | awk -F/ 'NF == 3'`)
 set old = `echo $file| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`
 set new = `echo $old  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
 set dirname=`basename "$file"`

  if ( -d "$new/$dirname" ) then
      mv   $file/* $new/$dir/
      rmdir $file

  else
     mkdir -p $new
     mv -f $file $new
  endif
  rmdir $old/*
  rmdir $old
  end
```

the output for the :

```
$file = ./11DATA20/CARTER/
$old =  ./11DATA20
$new =   DATA20
```

My problem is if there is duplicate files in $file/* while moving to new directory, the duplicate file will replace the old file in new directory. And also i need to rename the duplicate files when moving to new directory. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It assumes only files are to be moved. And it just appends _a to a filename so if you have special needs or do have directories you just change the shell script accordingly. I also renamed some variables but that was just for my own convenience.

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach topdir(`find . -type d -name \[0-9\]\* | awk -F/ 'NF == 2'`)
  set old = `echo $topdir| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`
  set new = `echo $old  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
  set from=`basename "$topdir"`
  #echo "$old $new $from"

  if (! -d "$new" ) then
    #echo "create new directory $new"
    mkdir $new
  endif

end

foreach topdir(`find . -type d -name \[0-9\]\* | awk -F/ 'NF == 2'`)
  set old = `echo $topdir| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`
  set new = `echo $old  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
  set from=`basename "$topdir"`
#  echo "$old $new $from"

  foreach subdir(`find $old/* -type d`)
    set base1 = `basename $subdir`
    if (! -d $new/$base1 ) then
      #echo "create $new/$base1"
      mkdir $new/$base1
    endif
  end

end

foreach topdir(`find . -type d -name \[0-9\]\* | awk -F/ 'NF == 2'`)
  set old = `echo $topdir| cut -f 1-2 -d '/'`
  set new = `echo $old  | cut -c 1-2,5-`
  set from=`basename "$topdir"`
  #echo "$old $new $from"

  foreach subdir(`find $old/* -type d`)
    set base1 = `basename $subdir`
    #echo "original directory: $subdir, new directory: $new/$base1"
    foreach source_files(`find $subdir/* -type f`)

      set from_file = `basename $source_files`
      set from_dir = `dirname $source_files`
      #echo "move file $from_dir/$from_file to $new/$base1"

      if (! -f $new/$base1/$from_file ) then
        mv $from_dir/$from_file $new/$base1
      endif

      if ( -f $new/$base1/$from_file ) then
        set append = "_a"
        set letter = "a"
        set to_file = "$from_file$append"
        #echo "new filename $to_file"

        while ( -f $new/$base1/$to_file )
          set append = "$append$letter"
          set to_file = "$from_file$append"
          #echo "file exist, change destination filename to $to_file"
        end

        mv $from_dir/$from_file $new/$base1/$to_file

      endif
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: error at find: bad option -mindepth, should i change find $old -mindepth 1 to find $old | awk -F/ 'NF == 2'?

Comment: I did this on os x yosemite. It uses the find version that is in the BSD-distribution. What OS are you on? Linux?

Comment: Solaris, AIX, HP/UX? These may not have mindepth but maybe an equivalent.

Comment: Strange. I found this man page for find on sunos 5.8 but you may be on a different solaris-version. http://www.manpages.info/sunos/find.1.html This has the mindepth. The reason I used mindepth was to prevent find from returning the folder itself. Maybe it can be changed to "find $old/*"?

Comment: i already changed to find $old/*"..but then the same folder name ; for ex:/11DATA20/CARTER/ and /12DATA20/CARTER/, the files inside the folder /12DATA20/CARTER is moved to DATA20 not to DATA20/CARTER...

Comment: Can the directory below 11DATA20 contain both files and directories? Or only directories, ie. CARTER? If so, shall the files in CARTER be moved to the new directory DATA20?

Comment: I'll modify the script so it hopefully will move files correct. Just some 'seconds'.

Comment: sorry for bothering you. i run the script and just change find mindepth to find $old/*..but the files not moved correctly...i have two different directory 12DATA20/CARTER and t 11DATA20/CARTER. but the files in  directory 11DATA20/CARTER not moving to DATA20/CARTER instead move to DATA20/CARTER/CARTER and DATA20..it supposed move to DATA20/CARTER and if there is duplicate file in DATA20/CARTER/ , it will rename it by append letter or number. For ex: if 11DATA20/CARTER/hart1 exist in DATA20/CARTER/hart1, hart1 will rename to hart1_2..

Comment: I have a new version of the script and will update my answer.

Comment: Can you try this? Now I perform three passes, first pass parses directories that should be renamed, ie. 11DATA20 and create DATA20. The second pass then find the subdirectories, ie. CARTER and create the directory in DATA20. The third pass then moves the files below CARTER, and if the file exists appends the letter a until it's unique.

Comment: Awesome. If you wish you can remove empty directories by a find from the top and just try a rmdir. It will only remove empty ones.

Comment: If you wish you can upvote and mark it as an answer.